# jboss-eap-7 static file cache looks like not working and I do not find any documentation on this

Tags: jboss-eap-7

I tried using the below tags in web.xml but no luck. Please suggest a valid approach. I am using standalone mode. Thanks

```
 <filter-name>imagesCache</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.samaxes.filter.CacheFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>static</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>expirationTime</param-name>
        <param-value>2592000</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>imagesCache</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

is this cache working in Jboss EAP 7 or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Try using buffer cache provided by undertow subsystem in EAP 7. Documentation can be found at official Red Hat site.

Comment: I don't see complete syntax of the undertow.

Comment: <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:4.0">
  <buffer-cache name="default"/>
  ....
</subsystem>  . You can use CLI to browse through various attributes.

Comment: Hello Sudhish, kindly share complete code block for standalone.xml